# Put files on android sdcard at apk installation

Tags: java, android, apk, embedded-resource

I need to copy some files embedded into my apk, to device's storage during app installation.
I can't use assets because a local web server will use these files.
Any way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just save all this files during onCreate inside your application class?

Comment: I don't want to copy all these files every time application is launched.

Comment: Just make a SharedPreference record that you've made a copy. Check SharedPreferences every time you launch your app. Consider using https://github.com/konmik/proxypref this lib. It's very helpful while dealing with Preferences.